# Excel - How To Reset Page Numbering At Manual Page Break

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with a sheet that is hundreds of pages long.  I wrote a macro that inserts a manual page break every time the contents of the selected column change.  I also want the page numbering to reset to 1 every time the contents of the selected column change, like if I was in Word and inserted a Section Break.  Does Excel have a special page break that resets the page numbering?  What is the VBA command for that page break?

Here is my code:

```
Dim HighlightRange As Range
Dim StoreCell As Range

Set HighlightRange = Selection
For Each StoreCell In HighlightRange
    ActiveSheet.Rows(StoreCell.Row).PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
    If StoreCell.Value <> StoreCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(StoreCell.Row).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    End If
Next StoreCell
```

Thanks!

Comment: there is no built-in page-break reset like this in Excel. It's a great question, but unfortunately, I don't think it's even possible to hard-code unique footers for **specific** pages within a worksheet . Also, I assume your selected column changes span more than one page in some or most instances? If not, you can hardcode a 1 in the `Custom Footer` for the sheet.

Comment: Yup, multiple pages.  Section 1 has 8 pages.  Section 2 has 12.  Section 3 has 7, etc.  And this will be a reusable template for a monthly process, so the amount of pages will be variable as well.

Could I write a script that creates a new sheet and cuts and pastes to that sheet?  The problem again being that there would be a variable number of sheets.  Then every book could have its own page numbering, right?

Comment: Yes. If you write a script that puts the separate sections on a separate `Worksheet` each `Worksheet` would then have it's own page number. Then you can `Select` all the sheets and print at once. It would renumber the pages starting on each new sheet. Good thinking :)

Comment: But how would I deal with the variable number of sheets? Also, each sheet would need to be created with a header with the column labels.

Comment: You would add a counter and loop and add a new sheet for each section change. You can easily copy the headers over from the *master* sheet or just create the holders in a holding sheet and copy them onto the new sheet as soon as its created, before copying the data.

Comment: The new sheets can be created in a new workbook/xlsx in the temporary directory. When you are done you can close it and delete it.